# Is there a way to load multiple URL's in a for loop

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to control RGB LED's with an ESP8266 module. But if i try to control multiple ESP8266 modules at once, the for loop only works for the last array element.

I've tried Toast.makeText(applicationContext, i.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
and the loop only counts 2 also if i remove the if statement.

The toast itself works fine on the AVD but not on my Galaxy S8.
The loading of all ips doesn't work on my phone and on the AVD.
Every time i try to control multiple devices only the last one lights up.
Here's my RGBActivity maybe I'm missing something.

```
iv_rgb.setOnTouchListener {
  _,
  event - >

  if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

    bitmap = iv_rgb.drawingCache
    val pixel = bitmap.getPixel(event.x.toInt(), event.y.toInt())

    var r = (Color.red(pixel) * brightness) / 100
    var g = (Color.green(pixel) * brightness) / 100
    var b = (Color.blue(pixel) * brightness) / 100

    val hex = "#" + Integer.toHexString(pixel)


    for (i in Devices.deviceIP.indices) {
      if (Devices.switch[i]) {
        wv_rgb.loadUrl("http://${Devices.deviceIP[i]}/?r${r.toString()}g${g.toString()}b${b.toString()}&")
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, Devices.deviceIP[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
      
       

      }

    }

  }
  true

}
```

Comment: What is `wv_rgb`?

Comment: Yes wv_rgb is a WebView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `wv_rgb' is a WebView than for a loadUrl you have to wait for event onPageFinished() (or onPageLoaded() forgot name).

Answer (score 0):

inside the loop you can try using onPageStarted() passing view url anf favicon and than call onPageFinished()(as stated by @blackapps) passing view and url. or try using conventional for loop(not sure, but worth a shot).

also you can look into this link https://android--code.blogspot.com/2016/03/android-detect-when-webview-finish.html

Comment: `and than call onPageFinished()(as stated by ...` One can not call onPageFinished(). It's an event. One can override it and place code in it which is executed ... when the page is finished.